# How to filter a trasaction model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to make transctions between two users.

models.py

```
class Trasaction(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    purpose = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    date   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.sender.username}"
```

I want to query for all transactions where a user is either a sender or a receiver.

views.py

```
def transactions_log(request):
    user = request.user
    transactions = Transactions.objects.filter #am stuck
    return render(request, "trasaction.html")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) objects, like so:

```py
from django.db.models import Q

def transactions_log(request):
    user = request.user
    transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(Q(sender=user) | Q(receiver=user))
    return render(request, "transaction.html", {"transactions": transactions})
```